# Monte Carlo estimate of m_coloring

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, montecarlo

I have some psuedo code from my book for the m coloring problem using the backtracking technique that looks like this:

```
void m_coloring(index i)
{
    int color;
    if (promising(i))
        if (i == n)
            cout << vcolor[1] through vcolor[n];
    else
        for (color = 1; color <= m; color++){
            vcolor[i + 1] = color;
            m_coloring(i + 1);
    }
}
bool promising (index i)
{
    index j;
    bool switch;

    switch = true;
    j = 1;
    while (j < i && switch){
        if (W[i][i] && vcolor[i] == vcolor[j])
            switch = false;
        j++;
    }
    return switch;
}
```

where the graph is represented by a two-dimensional array W which has both its row and columns indexed from 1 to n, where W[i][j] is true if there is and edge between the ith vertex and the jth and false otherwise;
this outputs all possible coloring of the graph suing at most m colors, so that no to adjacent vertices are the same color. The output for each coloring is an array vcolor indexed from 1 to n where vcolor[i] is the color ( an integer between 1 and m) assigned to the vertex.

I implemented this in Java and it worked. It is called using the call m_coloring(0). It ended up looking like this:

```
public static boolean W[][]= 
       {{false, false, false, false, false, false},
        {false, false, true,  true,  true,  false},
        {false, true,  false, false, true,  false},
        {false, true,  false, false, true,  false},
        {false, true,  true,  true,  false, true},
        {false, false, false, false, true,  false}};
public static int n = 5;
public static int m = 3;
public static int vcolor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
public static int promising = 0;
static void m_coloring (int i)
{
    int color;
    if (promising(i)){
        promising++;
        if (i == n){
            for (int k = 1;k <= n; k++)
                System.out.println(k + ": " + vcolor[k]);
            System.out.println();
        }
        else{
            for (color = 1; color <= m; color++){
                vcolor[i + 1] = color;
                m_coloring(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}    
static boolean promising (int i)
{
    int j;
    boolean Switch;
    Switch = true;
    j = 1;
    while (j < i && Switch){
        if (W[i][j] && vcolor[i] == vcolor[j])
            Switch = false;
        j++;            
    }
    return Switch;
}
```

Now the issue is implementing the pseudocode of the Monte Carlo Estimate. This looks like this in the book.

```
int estimate()
{
    node v;
    int m, mprod, t, numnodes;

    v = root of state space tree;
    numnodes = 1;
    m = 1;
    mprod = 1;
    while (m != 0){
        t = number of children of v;
        mprod  = mprod * m;
        numnodes = numnodes + mprod * t;
        m = number of promising children of v;
        if (m != 0)
            v = randomly selected promising child of v;
    }
    return numnodes;
}
```

So I created what I thought was a Java version of this:

```
public static int estimate(){
    int v[] = vcolor;
    int numnodes, m1, mprod, t, i;
    i = 0;
    numnodes = 1;
    m1 = 1;
    mprod = 1;
    while(m1 != 0){
        t = m;
        mprod *= m1;
        numnodes = numnodes + mprod * t;
        m1 = promising;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (m1 != 0)
            v[i] = rnd.nextInt(m1);
        i++;
    }
    return numnodes;
}
```

The problem is I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException every time I run it.  Is there anyone that can see what is wrong with my code or how I could better implement this Monte Carlo estimate code?

Answer (score 0):

I did run your code and there is no problem with it:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

private static final Random rnd = new Random();

public static boolean W[][]= 
       {{false, false, false, false, false, false},
        {false, false, true,  true,  true,  false},
        {false, true,  false, false, true,  false},
        {false, true,  false, false, true,  false},
        {false, true,  true,  true,  false, true},
        {false, false, false, false, true,  false}};
public static int n = 5;
public static int m = 3;
public static int vcolor[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
public static int promising = 0;

public static int estimate(){
    int v[] = vcolor;
    int numnodes, m1, mprod, t, i;
    i = 0;
    numnodes = 1;
    m1 = 1;
    mprod = 1;
    while(m1 != 0){
        t = m;
        mprod *= m1;
        numnodes = numnodes + mprod * t;
        m1 = promising;
        if (m1 != 0)
            v[i] = rnd.nextInt(m1);
        i++;
    }
    return numnodes;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println( estimate() );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In estimate(), you are cycling through your array 'v' as long as 'ml' is not zero.  Since 'v' is only 6 elements in length, your program goes out of bounds on your 7th iteration through that while() loop.  Change the while() loop to include checking for 'i':

```
while( m1 != 0 && i < v.length )
```

Also, the only change to 'ml' is an assignment to 'promising', and promising is never decremented, so ml will never be zero.  That makes your while() loop non-infinite.